# Simplify simple symbolic expression with KroneckerDelta

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebra

In short, my question is about finding a method for performing an automatic substitution `f[a]/.{a->b}`, where `b` depends on the form of `f`. Let me give here an example.

Suppose I have an expression like

```
A[b] B[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d + 1]
```

I would like to simplify this expression to get

```
A[d + 1] B[d]
```

(I know that this mapping can be mathematically incorrect, but this is what I would need to do).

In this example, applying `/.b->d+1` would indeed give the desired result. The problem is that my full expression is a very long equation of the type

```
A1[b] B1[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d + 1] + 
  A2[b] B2[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d - 1] + 
  A3[b] B3[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d] + ...
```

and I cannot do the above substitution manually per each term. Therefore, I'm looking for a method to get

```
(A1[b] B1[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d + 1] /. b->d+1 ) + 
  (A2[b] B2[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d - 1] /. b->d-1) + 
  (A3[b] B3[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d] /.b->d) + ...
```

Comment: Please learn how to typeset in *MathJax*.

Comment: The latter is not equivalent to the former even for the nonnegative integers. You ask something like how to do `2+2==5`.

Comment: you mention they're in a summation—but are they in an explicit `Sum[...]`, or are we trying to implement Einstein convention? if the former, it would be better to manipulate the whole `Sum` expression.

Comment: Maybe `A[b] B[d] KroneckerDelta[b, d + 1] /. b -> d + 1`.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher, I added an additional edit.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher Why not writing your solution as the regular answer? I think it would be useful.